# Warning assigning to _Nullable from incompatible type _Nonnull, but changing modifier does nothing

Tags: objective-c, types, protocols, compiler-warnings, objective-c-nullability

I have a protocol that defines the following method:

```
- (MyObj * _Nonnull)initWithManagedObject:(NSManagedObject * _Nonnull)managedObject dataManager:(id<DataManagerProtocol> _Nonnull)dataManager;
```

The class that implements it has a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak, readonly) id<DataManagerProtocol> dataManager;
```

The implementation of the method is like:

```
- (MyObj *)initWithManagedObject:(NSManagedObject *)object dataManager:(id<RHDataManagerProtocol>)dataManager
{
    // TEST
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Both the following lines cause the warning.
        // Changing nullability has no effect.
        self.dataManager = dataManager;
        //_dataManager = dataManager;
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is the exact warning:

> Assigning to 'id _Nullable' from incompatible type '__strong id _Nonnull'

Changing the nullability
 doesn't do anything.

EDIT: I have the following class extension in the .m file:

```
@interface MyObj ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<DataManagerProtcol> dataManager;

@end
```

Comment: A `weak` property can be `nil` by definition. This might clash with the `_Nonnull` annotation

Comment: Why is the `init` method calling `alloc`?

Comment: OK, you just rewrote your question's code. You still attempt to set a read-only property. Do you still get the same warning if you directly set the ivar like you need to?

Comment: @rmaddy I just commented on your answer.

Comment: And based on the comment you need to update your question with your class extension. That's quite important.

Comment: @rmaddy have now done. Apologies for the inclarity.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an Xcode bug. When I next started up my project (after restarting the computer) the error resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
~.delegate = (id)self;
```

Can fix this.